# Intersection Observer: Call a function only once per element

Tags: javascript, intersection-observer

I'm using the [Intersection Observer API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API) to track the visibility of multiple element on a web page. When an element becomes visible, a function `callback()` should be executed. The restriction: For each element, the function may only be executed once.

Here is my current implementation for a web analytics project:

```
const elements = document.querySelectorAll('[data-observable]');
const callback = str => { console.log(str); };
const observer = new IntersectionObserver(handleIntersection);

elements.forEach(obs => {
  observer.observe(obs);
});

function handleIntersection(entries, observer){
  entries.forEach(entry => {
    if (entry.intersectionRatio > 0) {
      // Call this function only once per element, without modifying entry object
      callback('observer-' + entry.target.getAttribute('data-observable'));
    }
  });
}
```

I'm struggeling to find a solution that does not modify existing elements, the IntersectionObserver or the IntersectionObserverEntries.

Usually I would use a closure to ensure that a function gets only executed once:

```
function once(func) {
  let executed = false;
  return function() {
    if (!executed) {
      executed = true;
      return func.apply(this, arguments);
    }
  };
}
```

But in this case I have difficulties applying the function because IntersectionObserver uses a weird callback iterator logic that get's executed everytime any element changes (instead of using a event-driven model).

Any ideas, how to implement a once per element function call that does not mutate other elements or objects?

Comment: Its not supported by IE, did you aware of that?

Comment: Yes, but I'm using a polyfill.

Comment: Do you still need the observer after the the functions called? If not, unobserve it once the function is called. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IntersectionObserver/unobserve

Comment: Yes, because I'm observing multiple elements. Registering one observer per element on the other hand would be possible but super wasteful.

Comment: but you can use function unobserve only for one element: observer.unobserve(entry.target);
For other elements observer will still calling

Answer (score 44, accepted):

As [James](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6518644/james) pointed out in the comments, the easiest solution to this problem is [unobserving](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IntersectionObserver/unobserve) the element once it has become visible and the callback has been invoked.

```
const elements = document.querySelectorAll('[data-observable]');
const callback = str => { console.log(str); };
const observer = new IntersectionObserver(handleIntersection);

elements.forEach(obs => {
  observer.observe(obs);
});

function handleIntersection(entries, observer){
  entries.forEach(entry => {
    if (entry.intersectionRatio > 0) {
      callback('observer-' + entry.target.getAttribute('data-observable')); 
      observer.unobserve(entry.target);
    }
  });
}
```

I didn't find any viable solution to use a closure to control how often a function can be called.